# What configurations can reference a security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

Odd question here.  I'm doing some work to remove *unused* security groups in many AWS accounts.  There is a Security Hub rule [EC2.22 Unused EC2 security groups should be removed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/securityhub/latest/userguide/securityhub-standards-fsbp-controls.html#fsbp-ec2-22) that identifies "unused" security groups.  For the most part this tells me what I need, but there are *some* security groups that are identified by this rule that I *don't* want to delete.  These are security groups that are not *currently* in use, but which are part of a configuration definition of some sort that could be used to launch resources in the future.  So while not technically used at present, they might *become* used when the underlying configuration is used to launch resources.

For example, a security group may show as "unused" by Security Group rule EC2.22 even though it is referenced in any of the following situations:

- In an EC2 launch template, but before any instances have been launched
- In a legacy EC2 launch configuration, but before any instances have been launched
- In an ECS service that has no running tasks at present

In those latent cases, I don't want to remove the security group--I want to treat it as "used" instead of "unused."  I am characterizing these situations as "latent security group configurations."

**What *other* latent configurations, if any, might reference a security group?**

Note, I am *not* asking about any of the real-time usage situations that EC2.22 checks--such as a security group used by an EC2 instance, by a running ECS service, by a lambda, by another security group, by an RDS DB, and so on which will block a security group from being deleted.

Comment: aws lambda is another one that can have security groups configured but not actually in use.  I didn't think EC2.22 would catch that  And for your launch templates, keep in mind that sometimes  they can be configured to scale down to 0, so that's another case where the referenced security groups might not be in active use, not just at creation time

Comment: @erik258 Lambda usage causes a network interface to exist, so it is not possible to delete a security group if it is associated to a lambda.  So security groups only associated to a lambda won't fail EC2.22--they are known to be "used."  Good clarification about launch templates and the other latent cases.  It is not just at definition time, but at any point when scaling causes no running resources to exist that may have the configuration used to launch them.